# Exception 29 [ESP8266] StoreProhibited

Tags: c++, arduino, excepciones, esp8266

En uno de mis proyectos me he encontrado con un error bloqueante en la placa "Wemos D1-R1" que utiliza un micro "ESP8266" cada 25 minutos. Esto provoca un reinicio, todo va bien y a los 25 minutos vuelve a reiniciarse sola.

Al pasar el error mostrado en la consola al [Exception Stack Trace Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) me muestra que se debe a:
<<*Exception 29: StoreProhibited: A store referenced a page mapped with an attribute that does not permit stores*>>

Estoy escribiendo esto por si le es útil a alguien.

Estuve lidiando con este problema una semana, hay muchas preguntas de este tipo en la web pero no he encontrado ninguna respuesta que se ajuste a mi caso, seguramente porque es un error que pueden darlo múltiples factores en la programación: quizás la wifi, el server creado, el FS, ...

En mi caso lo provocaba una función que se llamaba cada 3sg. en el loop principal y hacía una comunicación Serial de un puñado de bytes. Nada demasiado cargante en principio.

```cpp
    /** Envía un array de caracteres al puerto serie TX0 en formato binario */
    void toSerial(char arr[], uint8_t len){
      uint8_t len = 18;
      // check if Tx buffer is enough to write the string
      if (Serial.availableForWrite() > len) {
        Serial.write(new char[2]{'A', '1', 'B', '0', ...}, len);
        delay(100);
      }else{
        Serial.println("NO BYTES AVAILABLE IN BUFFER FOR SERIAL.WRITE");
        Serial.flush();
      }
    }
```

El problema en sí no era la comunicación Serial, sinó la creación de un *array de caracteres de 18 bytes de longitud*. **INCREÍBLE!**, tan poca cosa y al cabo de 25 minutos  se venía abajo el ESP por esta insipidez.

Comment: Entiendo que es una pregunta autorespondida, y la respuesta me parece perfecta, pero la pregunta no. Y aunque sea autorrespondida la pregunta debe contener todos los antecedentes necesarios para que cualquier usuario pueda responderla, no solamente tu.

Comment: Perdona, tienes razón. Símplemente no quise añadir código explicativo en la pregunta porque sería duplicado en la respuesta y no quería hacerla demasiado larga (que bastante larga es ya la respuesta que me "auto-respondí"). Pero viendolo ahora de lejos puede que sí, tendría que haber sido más explícito en la pregunta. Gracias Yussef!

Comment: No hay nada que perdonar, al contrario yo como aficionado a Arduino y similares, agradezco mucho la información. EL punto es que las preguntas y respuestas van por caminos separados, cada una ellas se evalúa y modera por sus propios méritos. La idea es que puedan existir muchas respuestas a una pregunta, porque en programación hay muchas formas de solución, entonces tienes que brindar la información necesaria para que otro pueda responder, y en una de esas alguien sale con una super respuesta y tú también te beneficias de ello....

Comment: Me parece que al menos tu primera parte de la respuesta puede incluirse como pregunta

Comment: Sí, es verdad, ... creo que voy a intentar editar la pregunta y la respuesta ...

Answer (score 0):

Ahondando en la [documentación del ESP8266](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) encontré:

> ... el comportamiento del operador **new** cuando se encuentra con escasez de almacenamiento dinámico ... provoca efectos secundarios ...

que se va comiendo la memoria vamos, y tiene que ver con:

> ... en entornos Arduino, **new** se sobrecarga para simplemente devolver el equivalente *malloc()* que a su vez puede devolver **nullptr**

... demasiado técnico para mí. Pero resumiendo creo entender que es mejor no crear nuevos objetos en el loop principal (aunque sean tan simples como un **char array**).

Bien, pues opté por sustituir la creación del nuevo array por la utilización de un **array global** de donde tomaba los elementos a través de su index; en vez de crear un nuevo array símplemente modificaba el global existente, más trabajo pero más eficaz.

```cpp
  uint8_t len = 4;
  char _TX_DATA[len] = {'A', '0', 'B', '1'}; //global char array
  /** Envía un array de caracteres al puerto serie TX0 en formato binario */
  void toSerial(char a, char b){
      // check if Tx buffer is enough to write the string
      if (Serial.availableForWrite() > len) {
        _TX_DATA[1] = a;
        _TX_DATA[3] = b;
        Serial.write(_TX_DATA, len);
        delay(100);
      }else{
        Serial.println("NO BYTES AVAILABLE IN BUFFER FOR SERIAL.WRITE");
        Serial.flush();
      }
  }
```

En el ejemplo utilizo un array de 4 elementos por simplicidad pero el que utilicé tenía 18.

De esta manera mi placa no volvió a darme problemas.

CONCLUSIÓN: No utilizar el operador **new** en el loop, no utilizar **alloc()** o **malloc()**, en Arduino conducen a un **abort()**, ... SE CONSUME LA MEMORIA!!

... o eso me ha parecido comprobar a mí ...

SALUDOS!

Comment: Según tu código, el problema no es **la creación** del *array*, sino el hecho de que **nunca lo liberas**. En cada iteración *usas* un poquito de la memoria disponible ... hasta que te quedas sin ninguna.

Comment: Con Arduino y otros MCU hay que evitar el uso de memoria dinámica. La estrategia es pedir toda la memoria al principio para evitar situaciones como esta

Comment: Teneis toda la razón del mundo Juanjo y Candid Moe. Gracias!

Comment: También puedes usar un arreglo en el stack. `char arreglo[] = {'A', '1', 'B', '0', ...}`. O `char arreglo[] = "A1B0..."`.